# WinForms utilizado en diferentes proyectos, error referencia WCF

Tags: c#

Tengo un formulario de búsqueda de productos, quiero utilizarlo en Requerimientos de productos, consulta de productos, en todo lo referente a búsqueda de productos, usarlo en diferentes proyectos como link, pero cuando lo abro en el siguiente proyecto, con el mismo nombre de referencia al WCF, resalta error y pide que se añada [nomgreproyecto].wcf.IService, pero si le agrego, en el primer proyecto ya no lo va a reconocer, ¿a alguien le ha pasado esto? no creo que tenga que crear el mismo formulario de búsqueda para los 10 proyectos que calculo hacer.

Comment: Asumo que tu formulario de búsqueda está en un componente DLL, para que pueda ser referenciado en otros proyectos WinForm. Dado lo primero, lo que debes hacer es agregar al app.config, de cada proyecto que llama al formulario (componente), la configuración de los Client Endpoint que se usan para llamar el Web Service.

Comment: Al final cree un proyecto que contiene todos los recursos compartidos, lo único que hago es referenciar a este proyecto desde los otros y todos funciona bien.